# How do I unsuppress a reported issue?

Tags: c++, llvm

After seven mounts of using QtCreator, I discover finally there are a Menu called **Analyze**. Clicking on it I saw there are many tools to use to analyze the C++ code, so I start with the first one: Clang.
The tool starts analyzing code and showing some issues. Accidentally I click on **Suppress this Diagnostic** on one of them, but it is suppressed forever even I restart the Clang analyze many times.

[image]

How I can un-suppress this entry and let Clang shows all issues?